# Taking input from a file in octave

Tags: machine-learning, octave

```
2 7
0.18 0.89 109.85
1.0 0.26 155.72
0.92 0.11 137.66
0.07 0.37 76.17
0.85 0.16 139.75
0.99 0.41 162.6
0.87 0.47 151.77
4                       // Number of queries
0.49 0.18
0.57 0.83
0.56 0.64
0.76 0.18
```

I am having a file having input data , the first line consists of number of feature and number of training set.
In octave How can i take the input from a file
My first Array:

```
  0.18 0.89 
  1.0 0.26 
  0.92 0.11 
  0.07 0.37 
  0.85 0.16 
  0.99 0.41 
  0.87 0.47
```

Second Array:

```
    109.85
    155.72
    137.66
    76.17
    139.75
    162.6
    151.77
```

After 4 quires to find the output.

Comment: Please state more precisely waht you want to do. Do you want to load the whole file into octave or only some lines? What syntax is "X[7][2] and Y[7][1]"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dlmread to read row 1 until 7 (0 is the first row) and all columns

```
octave:1> data = dlmread ("yourfile.txt", " ", [1 0 7 3])
data =

   1.8000e-01   8.9000e-01   1.0985e+02
   1.0000e+00   2.6000e-01   1.5572e+02
   9.2000e-01   1.1000e-01   1.3766e+02
   7.0000e-02   3.7000e-01   7.6170e+01
   8.5000e-01   1.6000e-01   1.3975e+02
   9.9000e-01   4.1000e-01   1.6260e+02
   8.7000e-01   4.7000e-01   1.5177e+02
```

Split the matrix into your wanted two:

```
octave:2> MyFirstArray = data(:, 1:2)
MyFirstArray =

   0.180000   0.890000
   1.000000   0.260000
   0.920000   0.110000
   0.070000   0.370000
   0.850000   0.160000
   0.990000   0.410000
   0.870000   0.470000

octave:3> SecondArray = data(:, 3)
SecondArray =

   109.850
   155.720
   137.660
    76.170
   139.750
   162.600
   151.770
```

Comment: i am solving [this problem](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/predicting-house-prices) so how i  make my required array